# Is there a way in Angular to use a compiled module with the lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module

As from the title, I'd like to know whether there is a way to use a compiled module for lazy loading?
If yes, my main thought goes to how Angular understands that from /dist folder it has to get the module that will be used for children paths

Comment: I doubt you can do that with Angular CLI, maybe with a custom build but i may be complicated. Hi again btw

Comment: Ok, thanks @YoukouleleY